# password_verify does not work when using hashed password from database

Tags: php, mysqli, php-password-hash

**SOLVED**

I had a strange problem with my registration form. JS were doing something strange and even though password_verify worked on login, the hash was different in some case... Now I fixed my code and it's working now! Thank you all guys!

**SOLVED**

I'm seriously trying to figure out why does my password_verify code isn't working for 4 days already and I'm getting really confused and mad...

First of all I have to say that session is already started and everything other is working without problems.

But when I try to create a password_verify script, it echo still the false...

field in database is named `password` and is set to `varchar 255`.

Password from database looks like this :

> $2y$10$GEw0Ie6r/Udz2hgJVkCy.ut99NY5NE.h8LEvNM1gBizA1tY58iNa6

That's good, that's what it should look like...

And when I echo the database password on my page, it shows the same, so it's good. But when I do `password_verify`, it's not working. It shows that `password_verify` is false... and I don't know why, because I'm 100% sure that the password I'm inputting in form is correct and matches with the db password. However, it does not work and it does not echo "DONE" as it should.

`echo strlen` shows 60

`echo $dbpassword` shows the hashed database password.

`echo $passwordsubmitted` shows the normal inputted password from form.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['changepassword'])){
    if($_POST['username'] !== $_SESSION['username']){
        echo "Invalid username";
    }
    else{
        $stmtselectvalues = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = ?");
        $stmtselectvalues->bind_param('s',$_SESSION['username']);
        $stmtselectvalues->execute();
        $stmtselectvalues->bind_result($dbpassword);
        $stmtselectvalues->store_result();
        while($stmtselectvalues->fetch()){
        $passwordsubmitted = $_POST['password'];
        echo strlen($dbpassword)."<p>";

        echo "Submitted password: ".$passwordsubmitted." and password from database: ".$dbpassword."<p>";
        if(password_verify($passwordsubmitted, $dbpassword) == false){
            echo "Invalid Password";
        }
        else{
            echo "DONE!";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<center>
    <form method='POST'>
        Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br>
        Password: <input type='text' name='password'><br>
        <input type='submit' name='changepassword'><br>
    </form>
```

But, when I use this code, it's working and echo is "DONE" so that means that password_verify is true...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['changepassword'])){
    if($_POST['username'] !== $_SESSION['username']){
        echo "Invalid username";
    }
    else{
        $dbpassword = password_hash("test", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $passwordsubmitted = $_POST['password'];
        echo strlen($dbpassword)."<p>";

        echo "Submitted password: ".$passwordsubmitted." and password from database: ".$dbpassword."<p>";
        if(password_verify($passwordsubmitted, $dbpassword) == false){
            echo "Invalid Password";
        }
        else{
            echo "DONE!";
        }
    }
}
?>
<center>
    <form method='POST'>
        Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br>
        Password: <input type='text' name='password'><br>
        <input type='submit' name='changepassword'><br>
    </form>
```

I really don't know why is this happening. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
Registration input is `<input type='password' name='password'>`

and submitted password from registration is hashed with this code :

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Comment: can you post the function `password_verify`?

Comment: @Populus - function? What do you mean?

Comment: @Populus [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: ah that one lol, I'm obviously out of touch :<

Comment: To me it seems that the problem arises, when you store the hash. Could you place the hash from your db `$2y$10$GEw0Ie6r/Udz2hgJVkCy.ut99NY5NE.h8LEvNM1gBizA1tY58iNa6`directly in your second example, instead of calling `password_hash("test", PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`? Could it be an encoding issue of your registration form, do you use UTF-8 for both pages?

Comment: @martinstoeckli - So I did as suggested by you and still the same false return.. I'm wondering because I use password_verify also for login script and login works perfectly... that's really weird. So there's no problem with password format in database in this case

Comment: Are you using the native password_verify function or the compatability library? If so what PHP version are you on?

Comment: @PeeHaa - Version 5.5 and I'm using password_verify

Comment: Can you repro on http://eval.in with a fake password?

Comment: @PeeHaa - I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on http://eval.in?

Comment: You mean login code or this one? and what exactly you want me to do? I've never seen something like eval.in :D

Comment: @StevenTomko: Please add the output of var_dump($passwordsubmitted, $dbpassword); before your password_verify() call to your post.

Comment: @Progman - Result is : string(8) "password" string(60) "$2y$10$15trkRMpvZ2Fbm.0fZSwx.b8y6UsmO22dV4PouDGAbw.ndtJHLPUW"

Comment: @StevenTomko: The hash with that password and seed should be "$2y$10$15trkRMpvZ2Fbm.0fZSwx.DjnbzDW5KPaNwiCUSMiPUGBwuuUM.t2", your hash in the database is wrong.

Comment: That confirms, that the problem is with the registration form (you did not hash the string 'password'). It would be helpful if we could see the code which calls the `password_hash()` function.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - So i was trying to figure out what was problem with my registration form, and I finally fixed it! it was javascript that was doing something strange even though the password_verify on login worked... Nevermind... Thank you all guys!

Comment: @Progman The data is salted with random bytes every time you hash...

Comment: @PeeHaa: `password_verify()` uses the same salt when generate the hash for comparison. In this particular case the salt was "15trkRMpvZ2Fbm.0fZSwx." and with that salt the `password_verify()` will generate the same hash. The same goes with `password_hash()` when using the `salt` key in the options array argument.

Answer (score -2):

The issue seems to be with the hashing. I've called `bcrypt()` with the same string parameter seven times and it returned seven different hash values, only the first seven chars are always the same $2y$10$:

```
$2y$10$C7FReGma/9fauYdufdNR3uleGKBgcl4vzL/tMjsksKOmNoPpcoaT2
$2y$10$f7ZjFAgyq5tNcG7dc8RsIuOPTPLFyJFK0RiWfPusE7gqs4.hpRH.u
$2y$10$PnQrq.C3NOdxyNwpWZowzOe77Dsc0Qdr5yzrMzHAV3rH7aqVZYslG
$2y$10$6LL9imr9qB3mnJaoDFsurOAqas4Co/6bN.6mgheHzSboLDtT.Q5hS
$2y$10$Rytiq/6HILN3Bm6cLT7ZM.rO.LjxuLY2xM2FZs3Pa9O2BXbH5H3vO
$2y$10$gg21TJ6GiJg6Wz7RVQkyfufHzlAzfTkKfOdOgsRKotKpsgAoFQErK
$2y$10$v8YdEIA25mBIi4jsrCDABuFzmITv.BuMr9YQl2RUN2xc1rmk0Po9a
```

The same issue with MD5(). So, when `password_verify()` compares the two
hashes it returns false.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. Random salts are essential. I have no idea how you can have "the same issue with MD5" though.